# Java - RandomAccessFile() format issue

Tags: java

My problem is when I get the data from a text file it seems to be in the wrong encoding or somthing. I dont know how to get around this issue sorry. Thanks in advance. Here is the code.

```
private static String readLogFile(String path, File f) throws IOException {
    if (f.exists()){
    String data;
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw")) {
            char ch = raf.readChar();
            raf.seek(f.length());
            String dataCh = String.valueOf(ch);
            data = dataCh.toString();
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        return data;
    }

    else{
        String data = "";
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the seek to EOF? Why are you calling toString() on a String? Why aren't you closing the file? WHy are you using a `RandomAccessFile` at all when you are just reading the start of it?

Comment: I have dumped this code as it had to many errors and now i am using FileInputStream . But yes the code about is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java Docs

> This method blocks until the two bytes are read, the end of the stream
>   is detected, or an exception is thrown.

Note, "two bytes are read"

Because Java supports Unicode character's the stream is automatically assuming that reading a character from the stream needs to produce a Unicode character.

Try `char ch = (char)raf.readByte();` instead